# 100 % cpu usage at EC2 windows machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, cpu-usage

i'm using windows machine over EC2 and i'm running a very heavy CPU consuming process.

my question is if it is dangerous to run a windows over EC2 that use 95-100 cpu most of the time?
is it can cause a crush of the machine or crush of the process?
is because the machine is using VCPU (virtual CPU) can i use 100? CPU with not casing any damage?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with that. The only thing you may need to be concerned about is that it can increase clock skew. If you regularly update your system clock you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

### No, not dangerous.

As datasage mentioned, it can increase clock scew, but that shouldn't be much of a problem.

The main reason it's not a problem is that it's *not actual hardware!* EC2 is a collection of virtual machines running on big, huge, servers - 100% of a Micro instance is about 0.1% to them.